# EXC_BAD_ACCESS While trying to extend UIView class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to extend the standard UIView class but I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCCESS error.

UIView+Depth.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Depth)
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize initialSize;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize angularSize;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat depth; // 0.0 ... 1.0
@end
```

UIView+Depth.m

```
#import "UIView+Depth.h"

@implementation UIView (Depth)
@dynamic initialSize;
@dynamic angularSize;
@dynamic depth;

- (CGSize)initialSize
{
    return self.initialSize;
}

- (void)setInitialSize:(CGSize)initialSize
{
    self.initialSize = initialSize;
}

- (CGSize)angularSize
{
    return self.angularSize;
}


- (void)setAngularSize:(CGSize)angularSize
{
    self.angularSize = angularSize;
}

- (CGFloat)depth
{
    return self.depth;
}

- (void)setDepth:(CGFloat)depth // This is where I'm getting the error while running.
{
    self.depth = depth;

    if (self.initialSize.width == 0 && self.initialSize.height == 0) {

        self.initialSize = self.frame.size;
    }

    // Angular size
    self.angularSize = CGSizeMake((powf(self.initialSize.width, 2) + powf(self.initialSize.height, 2)) * powf((1 - depth), 2) /
                                  (1 - (powf(self.initialSize.height, 2) / powf(self.initialSize.width, 2))),
                                  (powf(self.initialSize.width, 2) + powf(self.initialSize.height, 2)) * powf((1 - depth), 2) /
                                  (1 - (powf(self.initialSize.width, 2) / powf(self.initialSize.height, 2))));

    // Frame size
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - self.angularSize.width / 2,
                            self.center.y - self.angularSize.height / 2,
                            self.angularSize.width,
                            self.angularSize.height);
}
```

I use the @dynamic property in order to implement my own setter and getter methods.
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

I know I should have used:

```
_depth = depth;
```

Instead of:

```
self.depth = depth;
```

But, I can't get the "_" to work.

The compiler is throwing an en error "_depth not found" !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337633/properties-on-categories-how-do-i-handle-them-in-class-instances/24337870#24337870

Comment: It's giving you error because "_depth" doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do:

In implementation file import objective runtime - just include

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

underneath add static var

```
static CGFloat _depth;
```

replace setter and getter with the following code:

**getter**

```
-(CGFloat)depth {
    return (CGFloat) [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_depth) floatValue];
}
```

**setter**

```
-(void)setDepth:(CGFloat)depth {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &_depth , [NSNumber numberWithFloat:depth] , OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

    if (self.initialSize.width == 0 && self.initialSize.height == 0) {

        self.initialSize = self.frame.size;
    }

    // Angular size
    self.angularSize = CGSizeMake((powf(self.initialSize.width, 2) + powf(self.initialSize.height, 2)) * powf((1 - depth), 2) /
                                  (1 - (powf(self.initialSize.height, 2) / powf(self.initialSize.width, 2))),
                                  (powf(self.initialSize.width, 2) + powf(self.initialSize.height, 2)) * powf((1 - depth), 2) /
                                  (1 - (powf(self.initialSize.width, 2) / powf(self.initialSize.height, 2))));

    // Frame size
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - self.angularSize.width / 2,
                            self.center.y - self.angularSize.height / 2,
                            self.angularSize.width,
                            self.angularSize.height);
}
```

Apply similar solution to all properties added in the category

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinitely recurring method...

```
- (void)setDepth:(CGFloat)depth // This is where I'm getting the error while running.
{
    self.depth = depth; //same as [self setDepth:depth];
}
```

You have other problems as well. Adding ivars in a category is not so simple...

http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/